# How to use jquery.timeago plugin along with boundfield in the gridview?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, timeago

I have a simple grid view like this  :

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gv_userActivities" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="activity" HeaderText="Activity name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="activity_date" HeaderText="Activity date" />
            </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

---

Now  i wanna to use [jquery.timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) with my boundfield `Activity date`. How to access the bound field using script like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('gv_userActivities.timeago').timeago();
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a template field because the timeago plugin expects you to apply the title attribute to the corresponding DOM element and the date must be ISO 8601 formatted:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_userActivities" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="activity" HeaderText="Activity name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span class="timeago" title="<%# string.Format("{0:o}", Eval("activity_date")) %>">
                    <%# Eval("activity_date") %>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This obviously assumes that the `activity_date` property in your datasource is a DateTime instance. If it isn't the `ToString("o")` format won't work and you will have to manually build an ISO 8601 date in the title attribute that the timeago plugin can understand.

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.timeago').timeago();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks ,i don't know why this not works.

my gridview bind in the dropdownlist `selectedindexchanged`

Comment: @just_name, did you assign a `title` attribute to the `<td>` containing a ISO 8601 encoded date which is what the timeago plugin expects you to do?

Comment: my date time appears like this `12/03/2012 12:29:13 م`

Comment: which `td` should i assign the attribute?